# Meu filtro com expressões regulares não funciona

Tags: php

Não estou conseguindo fazer o filtro! 
quando coloco o sinal de negativo aparece ((entrou e passou)) quando tiro aparece passou porem se eu coloco caracteres estranho ele continua mostrando passou ou seja n esta filtrando!

```
<?php
    //$_GET['h'] vem em md5
    if(!isset($_GET['h']) || empty($_GET['h'])){
?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> window.location.href = "http://localhost/site/"</script>
<?php  
        exit();
    }

    if(!preg_match("/\w/", $_GET['h'])){
        echo"entrou";  
    }
    echo "passou";
?>
```

Comment: coloca o código ai pro pessoal te ajudar

Comment: tinha colocado porem esqueci de colocar para executar

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro uma dica, não precisa de `isset` se já esta usando `empty`, faça só isto:

```
 if (empty($_GET['h'])) {
```

A sua regex esta usando `\w` que é equivalente a fazer isto `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, no entanto a sua regex não afirma aonde começa e aonde termina, qualquer coisa como:

- `+a`
- `:a`
- `;a`
- `"a`
- `&a`

Note que tem caracteres estranhos, mas todos tem a letra "A", então vai passar, porque é o que a sua regex espera, que tenha qualquer letra, mesmo que tenha uma série de caracteres estranhos e esteja em qualquer **posição da string** veja o teste:

```js
var x = [
    'foo bar +a foo bar',
    'foo bar :a',
    'foo bar ;a',
    '"a',
    '&a foo bar'
];

var regex = /\w/;

for (var i = 0, j = x.length; i < j; i++) {
    console.log(x[i], '=>', regex.test(x));
}
```

Veja que todas retornaram `TRUE`

Agora se deseja checar se é um `md5` seria de 0-9 e entre a-f, só que é importante notar que isso não valida nada, só ajuda a checar se é um formato próximo, devendo ficar assim:

```
^[a-f\d]{32}$
```

O `^` checa a partir do começo, o `$` checa a partir do fim ou até o fim da string e o `{32}` checa se tem 32 caracteres.

Seu código todo ficaria assim:

```
<?php
    //$_GET['h'] vem em md5
    if(empty($_GET['h'])){
?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> window.location.href = "http://localhost/site/"</script>
<?php  
        exit;
    }

    if(!preg_match("^[a-f\d]{32}$", $_GET['h'])){
        echo"entrou";  
    }

    echo "passou";
?>
```

No entanto é importante notar que os carateres gerados em um MD5 são hexadecimais (a-f0-9), ou seja existe uma função **nativa do PHP** que pode checar se é hexadecimal, é a função `ctype_xdigit`, então basta saber se a string tem 32 caracteres, deve ficar assim:

```
$h = $_GET['h'];

if (strlen($h) === 32 && ctype_xdigit($h)) {
    echo"entrou";  
}
```

Comment: Sim, precisa utilizar `isset` antes de `empty` sim. A função do `isset` é checar se existe aquela váriavel, a função do empty é verificar se A VARIAVEL JÁ EXISTENTE esta limpa. Se você utilizar empty em um indice do GET que não existe, irá retornar um notice.

Comment: @juniorb2ss não precisa não, o empty faz os dois, da maneira que você fez e "não" emite o Notice acaso não exista.